# How to visualise route of vehicle in SUMO using TraCI/Python

Tags: python, sumo, traffic-simulation

I'm using Python to compute the possible routes of a vehicle from a point to another point of a map drawn in SUMO. I would like to use now TraCI to show these routes on the map by highlighting them. Is it possible via the API to select them and then use the `selection` visualisation to see the route in traci ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [traci.gui.toggleSelection](https://sumo.dlr.de/pydoc/traci._gui.html#GuiDomain-toggleSelection):

```
for e in route:
    traci.gui.toggleSelection(e, "edge")
```